# How do I break down a multi-valued key in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary

```
my_dict = { 
    ('X', 'A'): 5,
    ('X', 'B'): 2,
    ('Y', 'B'): 3,
    ('Z', 'A'): 3,
    ('Z', 'C'): 4,
    }
```

My goal is to see what are the keys 'X' are pared with.
For this example it should return ['A', 'B'].

However, order matters. So, 'A' should return None.

How can I break up the multi-valued keys to achieve that?

Comment: use `.keys()` to get tuples `('X', 'A')` and use `for`-loop to work with every tuple separatelly and use indexes `[0]` , `[1]` to get values from tuples.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I break up the multi-valued keys to achieve that?

Why not just have a 2-level dictionary?

In your current dict, `'X'` isn't a key, and because Python does not have a built-in btree (or other tree-based map) you can't select map subsets, however by making the two-level keys into two levels of keys:

```py
my_dict = { 
    'X': {
        'A': 5,
        'B': 2,
    },
    'Y': {
        'B': 3,
    },
    'Z': {
        'A': 3,
        'C': 4,
    },
}
```

You get exactly what you need:

- the values for (X, A) are at `my_dict['X']['A']`
- the sub-keys for Z are at `my_dict['Z'].keys()`
- all the values for Y (regardless of keys) are at `my_dict['Y'].values()`
- key might be missing? Use `dict.get` e.g. `my_dict.get('A')` => `None`, whereas `my_dict['Y']` => `{'B': 3}`

Comment: I'm working on a given dictionary, but I solved it using my_dict[x][a].
Thanks for the help, I'm new to python and never used dictionaries before.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for what you are trying to achieve

```
my_dict = { 
    ('X', 'A'): 5,
    ('X', 'B'): 2,
    ('Y', 'B'): 3,
    ('Z', 'A'): 3,
    ('Z', 'C'): 4,
    }
array = []
def getPair(value):
    for x in my_dict:
        if x[0] == value:
            array.append(x[1])
    return array;
            
        
print(getPair('X'))
```

Comment: What if 'X' is not at index 0?

Comment: If you read ops question you will understand that's what they want @MaxwellD.Dorliea

Comment: If you have a key like ("C", "X") your solution won't work.

Comment: op don't need the lookup on the second `x[1]` he/she needs it on the first `x[0]` hence the reason for op saying 'A' should return nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with list destructuring :

```
for (key1,key2),value in my_dict.items() :
    print(f"{key1},{key2}:{value}")
    if key1 == 'X' :
        print(f"X paired with {key2}, has value {value}")
```

If you only care about the keys:

```
for key1,key2 in my_dict.keys() :
    if key1 == 'X' :
        print(f"X paired with {key2}")
```

Performance-wise it iterates over the whole dictionary keys so it is not the most efficient but it is acceptable if you don't have a huge dictionary and it is unavoidable with your data structure.

If you need better performance, structure the data with a 2 layer nested dictionary `{ key1: {key2 : value , ... }, ... }` and then just access `my_dict[key1]` as suggested by
Masklinn.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Turns out that the multivalued keys in python are saved as an array. So you can just use `my_key[0]` to return the first value of the key and `my_key[1]` to return the second value of the key.